# Android Studio: error: invalid demon and "R" symbol cannot resolved

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have made my first simple project and it won't work. It says "error: invalid dimen".
dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">activity_vertical_margin</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">activity_horizontal_margin</dimen>
</resources>
```

Furthermore in my .java fails it says "cannot resolve symbol 'R'".

Clean project, synch with gradle and rebuild project didn't work.

How can i solve these errors?

Comment: Search on google.

Comment: i didn't find anything that solves my problems. Why do you think i am here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:- Put the actual dimension value in the dimen element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

After this Rebuild the project and error will be gone afterwords.

Comment: thanks now i got a more or less succesful build (sometimes it is so easy...). But my app keep stopping on a virtual device...

Comment: you are welcome buddy may be there are some coding errors that's why it's getting stopped check it out.

Comment: instead of using virtual device go for your own mobile to test your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set actual dimension not string, that's why you getting error, after this try clean and build project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">15dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">15dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

set your desire dimension size instead of 15dp.
hope it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening every time for me, so i need to fixed my issue with this 2 steps.

1) Delete ".gradle" folder in module inside of the project

2) Click on "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart" .

to get rid of the error.

Hope this helps